# react на node js на реальном сайте

Tags: php, node.js, reactjs, маршрутизация

Create React App is a comfortable environment for learning React, and is the best way to start building a new single-page application in React

Это написано в документации по react. Поэтому я думал, что это чисто для или разработки или вообще для того, чтобы понять как работает react. Но когда начал писать первое spa, собирал в одном файле js все компоненты и саму библиотеку и подключал к файлу index.php. Но есть проблема с маршрутизацией, при использовании react-rouer (это вроде как неважно, потому что любая маршрутизация js мне кажется использует history api), после изменении строки в браузере и после обновления страницы, эта строка посылается на сервер как запрос. В итоге нужно на бэкенде настроить маршрутизацию так, чтобы все запросы на index.php, используя красивые маршруты, то есть со слешами, шли только на index.php. Это единтсвенный способ? Или можно всё таки на реальном сайте использовать тот серверnode js для разработки, чтобы все запросы поступали на него, а уже компоненты, которые там работали, отправляли ajax-запросы на обычный apache и php?

Comment: А зачем вам объединять `Node.JS` и `PHP` - ? Это 2 бек-енд фрейма, выберете один и на нем делайте, скачки - излишки.

Comment: То есть первый способ правильный? При котором в один index.php подключается весь react?

Comment: Я подозреваю, что тот сервер `node.js`, который создается конструктором, и есть ни что иное как аналог вашего index.php с выводом html на все урлы с вашим app. Это просто для удобства локальной разработки. Так что если бек пишите на php, то nodejs там не нужен. Но и ничего страшного в использовании двух языков на беке тоже нет, nodejs может быть удобен для работы например с вебсокетами или для переформатирования апи например

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в ситуации перехода по прямой вложенной ссылке, чтобы клиентский роутер правильно обработал запрос, нужно поставить переадресацию со всех адресов на index.html За исключением картинок, цсс и т.д.

в ситуации, когда мы уже в приложении кликаем по внутренней ссылке никаких дополнительных запросов на сервер отправляться на должно, сервер может быть недоступен, но переход между страницами всё равно будет работать, ссылки должны быть относительными